# Creating a jump for a 2D character

Tags: unity-game-engine

I watched a video on YouTube on how to create a jump for a 2D hero, the code works, but when the character falls, his mass is not felt, in the RigitBody 2d component the mass value is set to mass, when I change it, the character does not feel it when he falls, how can I fix this?(unnecessary part of the code has been removed)
Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.Impl;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator anim;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private BoxCollider2D coll;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForse = 8.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask jumpableGround;
    private float dirX;
    private enum MovementState { idle, running, jumping, falling }
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        coll = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForse);
        }

        UpdateAnimationState();
    }
    
    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
       return Physics2D.BoxCast(coll.bounds.center, coll.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, 0.1f, jumpableGround  );
    }
       
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Mind including a few more details in your post? What do you mean by "not felt"? What is the behavior you see vs the one you expected?

Comment: dont ` rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);` every frame, you are changing his velocity all the time.

Comment: Are you expecting fall speed to depend on mass? That's not how it works. You should go to Project Settings => Physics and increase gravity. Mass only affects impact force, innertia etc.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the rd.Simulated is true? And you can use the AddForce() Method instead of velocity (it might be different you expect...)